# rest operator to omit properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to use the rest operator and restructuring to omit an entry in the object.  Based on the documentation, rest should no longer include the key entry 575. After the operation, rest still has the same keys as state. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```js
book = {
  id: 575,
  title: "Vector Calc"
};
state = {
  removedBooks: {
    46: {
      id: 46,
      title: "economics"
    },
    575: {
      id: 575,
      title: "Vector Calc"
    }
  }
};
const {
  [book.id]: data, ...rest
} = state;
console.log(rest);
```

EDIT: I am using React and it is not recommended to mutate the state object directly. [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really) among others

Comment: i'd do this procedurally. this makes your code really hard to follow.

Comment: why don't you just  do `delete state.removedBooks[575]`

Comment: In those code block you don't modify rest at all, you only read from it

Comment: @Berto99 Yes that would work but it's not a recommended approach for modifying state in React. Sorry didn't include the context.

Comment: @Leon That's how the rest operator works. You don't need to modify it for it to read a subset of the data. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: @BiniyamAsnake ah yes, I read your function wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The books are part of the `removedBooks` property, and are not direct children of the `state`. You need to destructure the `removedBooks` property as well.

```js
const book = {"id":575,"title":"Vector Calc"};

const state = {"removedBooks":{"46":{"id":46,"title":"economics"},"575":{"id":575,"title":"Vector Calc"}}};

const { removedBooks: { [book.id]: data, ...removedBooks } } = state;

const newState = { ...state, removedBooks };

console.log(newState);
```

Comment: Thank you @Ori. This definitively works in my chrome console. However, in my react component, I'm getting the wrong output. Im going to create another question focusing on that. It would be great if you can look at it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002070/rest-operator-for-deleting-property-in-object-not-working-in-react-component

Answer (score 2):

Your destructuring assignment expects a pattern of `{ 575: data, ...other... }` but `state` actually has `{ removedBooks: { 575: data, ...other... } }`. Add the `removedBooks` into your destructuring assignment and it works fine.

```js
book = {
  id: 575,
  title: "Vector Calc"
};
state = {
  removedBooks: {
    46: {
      id: 46,
      title: "economics"
    },
    575: {
      id: 575,
      title: "Vector Calc"
    }
  }
};
const { removedBooks: {
  [book.id]: data, ...rest
} } = state;
console.log(rest);
```